# Python - Text does not appear in code-triggered email sent if string is result of a formula

Tags: python-2.7, function, smtp, gmail

I am attempting to write a program that sends an email from Gmail, with a body of text that includes real time stock quotes. I am using a module to get stock quotes in string format (this works), and I wrote a function to send an email from gmail. The message_send function is only working if I give it a simple string. It is not working if I pass it the aapl_string variable. See code below:

```
from yahoo_finance import *
import smtplib

def message_send(messagebody):
    fromaddr = 'REDACTED'
    toaddrs  = 'REDACTED'
    msg = messagebody

    # Credentials (if needed)
    username = 'REDACTED'
    password = 'REDACTED'

    # The actual mail send
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
    server.quit()

aapl = Share('AAPL')

aapl.refresh()

price_aapl = aapl.get_price()

aapl_string = "The current price of AAPL is: " + price_aapl
print(aapl_string)

message_send(aapl_string)
```

Any ideas why the email sends, but contains blank text when using aapl_string as the argument for the message_send function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
message_send("The current value is %s" %price_aapl)
```

and that should make it work :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming price_aapl is an integer, and if that's the case then that is your whole problem. This is due to the inability of being able to add integers to strings so what you could do is use a format string.
ex:

```
    aapl_string = "The current price of AAPL is: %d" % price_aapl
```

the %d is a placeholder for the integer price_aapl.
You can look here -> http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html
for more information on formatting strings in python.

Comment: Forgot to add that - it is a string and the print statement towards the end of the code works

Comment: Oh ok then instead of %d you would just put %s